# create a gallery images in my website where there is albums that hold many pictures

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

i want to create a gallery images for each profile in my website where can the user upload many pictures and categorize it in albums but i do not know what is the logic to build such a thing so can anyone help me ??

i know i must create a form for allowing upload  my question is i must create in the database a field for holding paths of uploaded images images??

i did create a form that allow user to upload one picture as a profile but without having to save it in the database just save it a folder on on the server .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get you started in the right direction:

Create two tables in your database: userImages & userAlbums

userImages fields could consist of say:
id, location (where the file is saved on the server), userId (the owner's id from a user table), albumId, caption

userAlbums fields could consist of say:
id, userId(the owner of the album), title, description